# How to customized icon image on a dialog box

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, showdialog

I used a button click event to call the dialog box as follows:

```
private void btnDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    DialogResult result = BetterDialog.ShowDialog("Special Dialog", "large heading", "small explanation", null, "Ok", ***null***);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    // Action to perform ...
    }
    }
```

how can I specify the icon image from a given folder to show on the dialogbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
private void btnDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult result = BetterDialog.ShowDialog("Special Dialog", "large heading", "small explanation", null, "Ok", Image.FromFile(@"fullPath\FileName.ext"));
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
   {
   // Action to perform ...
   }
}
```

But it will change the image inside the dialog box, (if you want to change the icon of the dialog caption - i think it is not possible without modifying `BetterDialog` code)